# Generating R Bar plots based on X-axis data ranges

Tags: r, rstudio, bar-chart

I have a data set as below.

```
Time
1
1
2
2.6
2
2
8.81
3.01
3
5.56
1.6
6.6
```

I need to generate a bar plot based on data ranges (Eg. 0-2,2-4,4-6,6-8 etc).

For an example, bar plot will have data as follows.

X axis - Time ranges
Y axis  - Frequency

```
Time Range   Frequency

0-2         6
2-4         3
4-6         1
6-8         1
8-10        1
```

Comment: You can check `?cut` and `table`, i.e. `barplot(table(cut(df1$Time, breaks = seq(0, 10, by = 2))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create the groups with `cut`, get the frequency using `table` and generate the bars with `barplot`

```
barplot(table(cut(df1$Time, breaks = seq(0, 10, by = 2))))
```

---

If we need the custom labels, use the `labels` argument in `cut`

```
barplot(table(cut(df1$Time, breaks = seq(0, 10, by = 2), 
      labels =paste(seq(0, 8, by =2), seq(2, 10, by = 2), sep="-"))))
```

[image]